# still not in sudoers file when add my username to group wheel

Tags: sudo

I've followed this [instruction](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-sudo-user-on-centos-quickstart)

And It still give me the warning `cchaney is not in the sudoers file . This incident will be reported.` when I try to test if it's working. But I've execute the command `usermod -aG wheel cchaney` under `root` user. what's going on???

Comment: Have you logged in again after the `usermod`? IIRC, groups are only looked up when you log in (e.g. opened a new terminal window).

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz !! it's work. that's the point

Answer (score 4):

The `wheel` group itself needs to allow running commands accordingly; it should also be noted that use of `wheel` for such access is distrobution / OS dependent. macOS and Red Hat use it, Ubuntu just uses a `sudo` group.

Run `visudo` as root and locate the `wheel` group.

If it is not defined in the file, add

```
%wheel ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

And save. This should not require a logout at this point, if your user is in `wheel` already.

Comment: I got caught by the same issue discussed in [this forum thread](https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?267644-I-m-in-the-wheel-group-sudoers-allows-wheel-but-I-can-t-sudo) and [this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/521591/user-in-sudo-group-cannot-use-sudo-command#comment987662_521636): not realising I had missed the `%` in `%wheel`. `visudo` won't pick this up as an error, because it's a valid way to grant permission to the `wheel` user.

Comment: I do have this line in `visudo`, with the `%` sign, my user is in `wheel` (`groups myuser` lists `myuser : myuser wheel`), I did log out and logged in, yet Red Hat 8 still said "user is not in sudoers file". A reboot did it! `sudo` works after a reboot.